# Чтение содержимого определенных строк таблицы в Word при помощи библиотеки docx python

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

Задача записать содержимое из таблиц word не трогая заголовки.
Так выглядят таблицы в word'е.
Мне нужно взять содержимое верхней и нижней таблицы.
[image: Пример таблиц в word'е]
Так выглядит код который я пытаюсь использовать для этого

```
from docx import Document

wordDoc = Document('D:/dataforpython/FormsDoc.docx')

for table in wordDoc.tables:
    for row in (table.rows[1],table.rows[-1]):
        for cell in row.cells:
            print (cell.text)
```

Пример кода я брал отсюда
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366596/how-to-read-contents-of-an-table-in-ms-word-file-using-python/31849166#31849166

Так выглядит вывод

[image: Выход]

Проблема в том что в цикле я указываю первую и последнюю строку, думая что он будет проходить от начала и до конца. Но он так не делает. Проблема в том что я не указываю range перед скобками верно? Но если я пишу range python выдает ошибку
[image: Ошибка]

Тогда я пробую заменить содержимое скобок на integer

```
from docx import Document

wordDoc = Document('D:/dataforpython/FormsDoc.docx')

for table in wordDoc.tables:
    for row in range(1,-1):
        for cell in row.cells:
        print (cell.text)
```

Python уже не выдает ошибку, но и программа тогда ничего не выводит.
Я не знаю как можно починить эту ошибку.
Возможно есть более легкое решение, но я его не знаю.
Надеюсь вы подскажите хотя бы правильно направление в решении этой проблемы.
Есть ли у вас идеи как можно было бы упростить занесение данных из цикла в массив numpy или таблицы pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для меня сработал такой код.

В dataframe я брал только 2й столбец. По аналогии можно сделать и 1й.

```
from docx import Document

wordDoc = Document('D:/dataforpython/FormsDoc.docx')

table_size = len(wordDoc.tables[1].rows)
n_report = wordDoc.tables[0].rows[-1].cells[0].text
date_report = wordDoc.tables[0].rows[-1].cells[1].text

dataframe = []
for i in range(1,table_size):
    dataframe.append(wordDoc.tables[1].rows[i].cells[1].text)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dataframe)
print(dataframe)
```